# How to read from a redirected file instead of taking command line parameters

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I am writing a program where if no command line arguments are supplied i.e @ARGV == 0, the program takes in three inputs. But, the program has the feature to read any files given as arguments, thus

```
calculate input1 input2
```

runs the formula on the numbers found in file1 and file2.

The problem I am running into is when I run

```
calculate < input1
```

@ARGV returns 0, thus it runs the code for user input.

How do I get around this so that the program can read input1 and use the values inside for calculations?

Comment: You have no shown us any code. That’s a problem. We cannot divine what is going wrong if you will not show us.  Are you manually opening and reading from particular files?  Please show the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`calculate < input1` is equivalent to `cat input1 | calculate`.

You need to read from `<STDIN>` and not look for command line arguments.

Comment: Just do something like: `@file_input = <STDIN>;`

Comment: No, just read from `<>`.  It doesn’t matter then. Also, please don’t read the stream into memory all at once.  The line-processing pattern is `while (<>) { ... }`.

Comment: @tchrist: Is there a good reason why you would never read the stream into memory all at once? I often will do that if I know the file is small enough to not be a problem.

Comment: Sam: Code Defensively. You don't want to get into that habit and then forget to do it the "right" way in an environment where the size of the file isn't predictable.

Answer (score 2):

That should not be a problem.  If you read reading from `<>` (which is really `<ARGV>`), then there is no difference.

You must be doing something wrong if redirection changes things.  Are you actually opening files yourself???

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a module like [Getopt::Euclid](http://search.cpan.org/~kgalinsky/Getopt-Euclid-v0.2.3/) or [Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/~jv/Getopt-Long-2.38/) to make the argument passing more explicit. That might make the program easier to understand for other users too.

Comment: Who said there were options??